# R caret only specify indexOut in trainControl

Tags: r, r-caret

This might be a stupid question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. In the trainControl the indexOut argument can be used to specify what part of the data should be used for testing during cross-validation. Will all other points of the dataset automatically be used for training or is it necessary to specify index as well?

R documentation states:

> index: a list with elements for each resampling iteration. Each list element is a vector of integers corresponding to the rows used for training at that iteration.
>
> indexOut: a list (the same length as index) that dictates which data are held-out for each resample (as integers). If NULL, then the unique set of samples not contained in index is used.

This specifies that if only index is given all remaining points, not used for training, will be used for testing. It however does not specify if this also works the other way around.